# Is there any way to create/update/delete event in Outlook using Graph api without sending webhook notification even when subscribed

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, webhooks, outlook-calendar, microsoft-graph-webhooks

If i create/update any event using **graph API**, microsoft will send a notification to **subscribed webhook**. How can i identify that the notification is of same updated event by graph API, so that I can **ignore** it and **don't do any action** on the event.

Answer (score 0):

When notification arrives, check response property of notification. This response contains url of resource for which notification belongs. Now by help of this response url you can call graph api to get further data of that event. By that way you will able to get event id. You can now check this event id with updated one and ignore it.